# ASP .NET Web API how to read cookie from api controller in mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My Api Controller

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        var valueSession = new NameValueCollection();

        valueSession.Add("user_id", 1);
        CookieHeaderValue cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("session", valueSession);
        cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(2);
        cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
        cookie.Path = "/";

        response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });

        return response;
    }
}
```

My Controller - I need to retrieve the cookie I set from API to this controller. Any Suggestion?

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    // GET: User
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: From where are you calling your API endpoint??

Comment: I will call it in mvc controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    var userIdVal = Request.Cookies["session"].Values["user_id"];
    return View();
    //do something
}
```